Angular 17 es build success but not create file on dist folder
i used angular 17.3.7
my config in build.development  : enter image description here
my config in serve enter image description here
build with ng build success and create file on dist folder
build with ng sever success but not create file on dist
any ideal for that ?
i tried re install node module

Welcome to stackoverflow. Please do not post your data with image. See here for detail.
